# Android Bitmap color to alpha

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, mask, antialiasing

I have a "multi-mask" bitmap, i need to use its different colored area to separately mask different parts from another bitmap.

This code is a working example but of course i have aliasing issues on edges

```
    // Bitmap bmpsrc    - source bitmap to be masked
    // Bitmap multimask - contains the colored masks
    // Bitmap mask      - selective mask depending on color range
    int w=bmpsrc.getWidth();
    int h=bmpsrc.getHeight();
    Bitmap mask=Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // rgb color range example, use dark gray 0x20 only
    int rgb_min=0x00202020;
    int rgb_max=0x00202020;

    int r_min=rgb_min&0x00FF0000;
    int r_max=rgb_max&0x00FF0000;
    int g_min=rgb_min&0x0000FF00;
    int g_max=rgb_max&0x0000FF00;
    int b_min=rgb_min&0x000000FF;
    int b_max=rgb_max&0x000000FF;
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            int color = multimask.getPixel(x, y);
            int a=color>>>24;       // discard sign (when alpha>0x7f color is negative!)
            int r=color&0x00ff0000;
            int g=color&0x0000ff00;
            int b=color&0x000000ff;

            if(
                    a>0&&                   // check alpha>0
                    r>=r_min&&r<=r_max&&    // check r in range
                    g>=g_min&&g<=g_max&&    // check g in range
                    b>=b_min&&b<=b_max      // check b in range
            ) {
                mask.setPixel(x, y, a<<24|0x00ff0000); // outputs mask
                //mask.setPixel(x, y, a<<24|(0x00ffffff&bmpsrc.getPixel(x,y))); // outputs masked image
            } else {
                mask.setPixel(x, y, 0x00000000);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
"multimask" image
[image]
mask example, 0xff202020 color extracted (aliasing)
[image]
masked image, aliasing!

My questions:

1. How to achieve this result using ColorFilter (ColorMatrix or PorterDuff), assuming it is possible?
2. ColorFilter vs getPixel/setPixel, what about performance?
3. Some suggest not to use `getPixel()`, but i need to check pixel one by one, how can i use `getPixels()` instead?
4. Any idea about the aliasing problem on the edges?